# Multi-Store Magento - On CDN - Possible?

Tags: multistore, cdn

I have a multi-store magento install.
I have a CDN with Trustwave.

Currently I have only setup 1 store on the trustwave CDN.
And have changed that one store's DNS to point to the CDN.

Do you think it is possible for me to point the other URLs to that CDN as well?
Or do I have to get a new CDN per URL (even though all my stores are on the same server/ip/magento install)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set the CDN for each individual website in you configuration. You will change it in the same place you have changed the URL's for your other store views.